# Sequelize doesn't clean up dataValues when overriding underscored fields

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Sequelize version: 3.24.3
Dialect: MySQL

for some reason when I print out the result of a findById I get the following:

```
{ id: 1,
  adminUserId: 16,
  expiration: 2018-01-25T19:45:04.000Z,
  admin_user_id: 16 }
```

I am expecting to see something like this

```
{ id: 1,
  adminUserId: 16,
  expiration: 2018-01-25T19:45:04.000Z }
```

without the duplicated underscored Id.

here is my model definition:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Device = sequelize.define('Device', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    adminUserId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field: 'admin_user_id',
    },
    expiration: DataTypes.DATE,
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'device',
    timestamps: false,
      classMethods: {
          associate: function (model) {
              Device.belongsTo(model.AdminUser, { foreignKey: { name: 'adminUserId', field: 'admin_user_id' } });
          },
      },
  });
  return Device;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const db = Sequelize({
  database: 'name_of_db',
  dialect: 'mysql'
  define: {
   underscored: true
}
```